# masm errors : error A2006: undefined symbol : BEGIN

Tags: windows, assembly, masm

I try to use MASM6.15 on win7(32bit) to write an interrupt solving program.

But I get two strange error message when compiling.

> Assembling: int7.asm
>
> int7.asm<19> : error A2206: missing operator in expression
>
> int7.asm<77> : error A2006: undefined symbol : BEGIN

I had marked this two line in the demo.
Thanks a lot!!

```
    DATA    SEGMENT
    COUNT   DW  1
    MSG     DB  0DH,0AH,'THE BELL IS RINGING!',07H,0DH,0AH,'$'
    FLAG    DB  0
    DATA    ENDS

    CODE    SEGMENT
        ASSUME  CS:CODE,DS:DATA
    MAIN    PROC    FAR
    BEGIN:  PUSH    DS
            XOR     AX,AX
            PUSH    AX
            MOV     AL,1CH
            MOV     AH,35H
            INT     21H
            PUSH    ES
            PUSH    BX
            ;----------------------
            MOV     DX,OFF SEG RING
            MOV     AX,SEG RING  ; it shows error here : missing operator
            MOV     DS,AX
            MOV     AL,1CH
            MOV     AH,25H
            INT     21H
            ;----------------------
            IN     AL,21H
            AND     AL,11111110B
            OUT     21H,AL
            INT     21H         
            STI
            ;----------------------
            ;REPEAT 
    DELAY:  MOV     SI,1000H
    DELAY1: DEC     SI
            JNZ     DELAY1       
            AND     FLAG,01H       
            JNZ     EXIT1
            DEC     SI
            JNZ     DELAY1  
    EXIT1:  MOV     FLAG,0
            MOV     COUNT,1
            POP     DX
            POP     DS
            MOV     AL,1CH
            MOV     AH,25H
            INT     21H
            RET
    MAIN    ENDP
    RING    PROC FAR
            PUSH    DS
            PUSH    AX
            PUSH    CX
            PUSH    DX
            MOV     AX,DATA
            MOV     DS,AX
            STI
            DEC     COUNT
            JNZ     EXIT
            MOV     DX,OFFSET MSG
            MOV     AH,09H
            INT     21H
            MOV     COUNT,182
            MOV     AH,0BH
            INT     21H
            CMP     AL,0
            JZ      EXIT   
            MOV     FLAG,1
     EXIT:  CLI
            POP     DX
            POP     CX
            POP     AX
            POP     DS
            IRET
    RING    ENDP

    CODE    ENDS
    END    BEGIN    ; it shows that BEGIN is undefined symbol
```

Comment: `MOV     DX,OFF SEG RING`  <-- Did you mean `MOV DX, OFFSET RING`  ?

Comment: Just as an FYI: there's no reason that assembly code has to be all caps.  I don't know why so many asm examples and tutorials use all caps, but it's something that I think people should move away from.

Comment: I am sorry, I had changed it but it still has the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MOV DX, OFFESET RING`

then

why `END BEGIN`?
`BEGIN` is simply a label rather than a segment name or a process name

remove `END BEGIN`and add `END` at the end of file

-----UPDATED-----

Or maybe you want to tell the linker where the program start if you try to use a small memory model.At this time ,you do need to add this line **at the end of file**: `end BEGIN`.which will tell linker the label BEGIN is exactly the place where this program should start at.

However, you may get an error from assembler sometimes. like this:

> error A2006: undefined symbol : BEGIN

then you should try to move your `BEGIN` label **out of** the main procedure(the one you want it to be the entry of this program).And the program looks like :

```
DATA    SEGMENT
COUNT   DW  1
MSG     DB  0DH,0AH,'THE BELL IS RINGING!',07H,0DH,0AH,'$'
FLAG    DB  0
DATA    ENDS

CODE    SEGMENT
    ASSUME  CS:CODE,DS:DATA
BEGIN:
MAIN    PROC    FAR
 PUSH    DS
        XOR     AX,AX
        PUSH    AX
        MOV     AL,1CH
        MOV     AH,35H
        INT     21H
        PUSH    ES
        PUSH    BX
        ;----------------------
        MOV     DX,OFFET RING
        MOV     AX,SEG RING  ; it shows error here : missing operator
        MOV     DS,AX
        MOV     AL,1CH
        MOV     AH,25H
        INT     21H
        ;----------------------
        IN     AL,21H
        AND     AL,11111110B
        OUT     21H,AL
        INT     21H         
        STI
        ;----------------------
        ;REPEAT 
DELAY:  MOV     SI,1000H
DELAY1: DEC     SI
        JNZ     DELAY1       
        AND     FLAG,01H       
        JNZ     EXIT1
        DEC     SI
        JNZ     DELAY1  
EXIT1:  MOV     FLAG,0
        MOV     COUNT,1
        POP     DX
        POP     DS
        MOV     AL,1CH
        MOV     AH,25H
        INT     21H
        RET
MAIN    ENDP
RING    PROC FAR
        PUSH    DS
        PUSH    AX
        PUSH    CX
        PUSH    DX
        MOV     AX,DATA
        MOV     DS,AX
        STI
        DEC     COUNT
        JNZ     EXIT
        MOV     DX,OFFSET MSG
        MOV     AH,09H
        INT     21H
        MOV     COUNT,182
        MOV     AH,0BH
        INT     21H
        CMP     AL,0
        JZ      EXIT   
        MOV     FLAG,1
 EXIT:  CLI
        POP     DX
        POP     CX
        POP     AX
        POP     DS
        IRET
RING    ENDP

CODE    ENDS
END    BEGIN
```